# Using a package before publishing it

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am currently developing a dart package and would like to use it in another dart project without having to publish it on Dart-pub.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes ! You have to use `path` in `pubspec.yaml` to link the directory of your dependency. See [Path packages](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages).